# Change project key with bitbucket rest api

Tags: python-requests, bitbucket, bitbucket-api

I am trying to write a script to move repos in a project to another project but I am getting a 400 error whenever I try.

My python requests line looks like:

```
url = 'https://bitbucketserver.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/example1/repos/repo1'
token = 'TokenString'

response = requests.put(url, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token}, data={'project': {'key': 'NEW_PROJECT'}}, verify=False)
```

I get a response 400 that says 'Unexpected character ('p' (code112)): expected a valid value (number, string, array, object, true, false, or null) at [Source: com.atlassian.stash.internal.web.util.web.CountingServletInputStream@7ccd7631; line 1, column 2]

I'm not sure where my syntax is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Not python, but work for me via curl:

```
curl -u 'USER:PASSWORD' --request PUT \
  --url 'https://stash.vsegda.da/rest/api/1.0/projects/OLD_PROJECT/repos/REPO_TO_MOVE' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
    "project": {"key":"NEW_PROJECT"}
}'
```

Maybe can someone help.